# Closed form for the following sum of Binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to find a closed form for the following for any $p$
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{m - 1} p^{n} \binom{2m}{n}
$$

I typed this into Wolfram Alpha and got an answer in terms of the hypergeometric function, which I confirmed using [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) page and the first formula under the section named "Generating Functions" in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Divisibility_properties) Wikipedia article; however, the hyperbolic geometric function diverges when $|p| > 1$ based on the the words under equation (9) in [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) link.

**What would be a closed form expression for this finite summation**?

Comment: For $|p|>1$ rewrite the summation as $$S(p) = \sum_{n=0}^{2m} p^n{2m\choose n} - \sum_{n=m}^{2m}p^n{2m\choose n}$$ $$ = (1+p)^{2m} - p^{2m}\sum_{n=0}^m p^{-n}{2m\choose n}$$ Then the same formula applies for $|p^{-1}| < 1$ that you used for the original summation.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you very much!

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/302167/305862).