# How to calculate (or approximate) "trimmed" (a+b)^n?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation

$a^n + C_n^{1}a^{n-1}b + ... C_n^{n-1}a^{1}b^{n-1}+b^n = (a+b)^n$

But  how to calculate (maybe approximately)

$a^n + C_n^{1}a^{n-1}b + ... C_n^{i}a^{n-i}b^{i} = ?$

For info, the underlying problem is "How many $n$ packets should I send to deliver at least $i$ packets successfully if packet loss probability is $a$".

Comment: A [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/84746/2370).

Answer (score 0):

If one of $a,b$ is much larger than the other you can ignore the terms with high powers of the small one.  Say $a \ll b$, corresponding to most packets getting through.  Then your expression is $(a+b)^n=b^n(\frac ab +1)^n= b^n\left(1+n\frac ab+\frac {n(n-1)}2(\frac ab)^2\ldots +(\frac ab)^n\right)$.  Keep as many terms as you need to get the accuracy you want.  If $\frac{na}b \ll 1$ they will decrease rapidly.

Comment: I expect $a$ to be from about 2% to 80% (i.e. from improving slight problems to hammering thought serious networking issues).