# Is this binomial coefficient identity already known?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$ \sum_{k=r}^{n} {n \choose k} = \sum_{k = r - 1}^{n-1}{k \choose r -1}2^{n-1-k}  $

The proof is trivial but I haven't seen this identity anywhere. Perhaps it's a special case of a more general identity?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84746/bounds-on-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk-and-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk1

Answer (score 0):

Whatever sums of hypergeometric terms are around can be solved by the techniques of Petkovsek, Wilf, Zeilberger's ["A = B"](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)