# Sufficient conditions for bound

Tags: inequality

Let $m\leq n$ be nonnegative integers and $x > 0$. I would like to find  sufficient conditions on $m,n,x$ (as tight as possible) s.t.

$$\frac{ \binom{n}{m} \sum_{j=0}^m j\binom{n}{m-j}x^j }{ x \left( \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{n}{m-j} x^j \right)^2 } < 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* This is only a *rudimentary answer* to your question together with some additional information at the end.

> A short overview:

- We *transform the inequality* to gain some insight in the structure
- Results for a few *special values*
- Some *references* related to this question

> **First step** Transformation of the inequality

The idea is to transform the inequality so that we can better see, which parts are responsible to invalidate it.

\begin{align*}
0<x\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m-j}x^{j}\right)^2-\binom{n}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m-j}jx^j\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Regrettably we hardly have a chance to find a closed formula for
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{j}x^j \qquad 0\leq m\leq n\tag{2}
\end{align*}
since as you can read e.g. in the second edition of

> [Concrete Mathematics](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf) from Graham, Knuth and Patashnik
>
> There is *no closed form* for the partial sum of a row of Pascal's triangle.

But we find another interesting hint in section 5.1 for a closed formula in case (2) is *multiplied by it's distance to the center*:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{j}\left(\frac{n}{2}-j\right)=\frac{m+1}{2}\binom{n}{m+1} \tag{3}
\end{align*}

We use a similar technique to transform the inequality and so unify the sums from (1).

> Let 
>   \begin{align*}
> A_{m,n}(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}\qquad 1\leq m\leq n
> \end{align*}
>   then
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m-j}x^{j}&=\binom{n-1}{m}+(1+x)A_{m,n}(x)\\
> \sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m-j}jx^{j}&=m\binom{n-1}{m}+\left(m-(n-m)\frac{1}{x}\right)A_{m,n}(x)\\
> \end{align*}

*Note:* We use the convention, that the empty sum and binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{j}$ with $n<0$ is considered to be $0$.

The statement above is valid since
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{m}&\binom{n}{m-j}x^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{j}x^{m-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j-1}x^{m-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}+\frac{1}{x}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}\\
&=\binom{n-1}{m}+(1+x)A_{m,n}(x)\\
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{m}&\binom{n}{m-j}jx^{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{j}(m-j)x^{m-j}\\
&=m\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{j}x^{m-j}-\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{n}{j}jx^{m-j}\\
&=m\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{j}x^{m-j}-n\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j-1}x^{m-j}\\
&=m\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j-1}x^{m-j}\right)\\
&\qquad-\frac{n}{x}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}\\
&=m\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}+\frac{1}{x}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}\right)\\
&\qquad-\frac{n}{x}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{n-1}{j}x^{m-j}\\
&=m\binom{n-1}{m}+\left(m-(n-m)\frac{1}{x}\right)A_{m,n}(x)\\
\end{align*}

> Now putting all together gives
>
> \begin{align*}
> 0<&x\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m-j}x^{j}\right)^2-\binom{n}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m-j}jx^j\\
> &=x\left(\binom{n-1}{m}+\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)A_{m,n}(x)\right)^2\\
> &\qquad-\binom{n}{m}\left(m\binom{n-1}{m}+\left(m-(n-m)\frac{1}{x}\right)A_{m,n}(x)\right)\\
> \end{align*}

And after some rearrangement we finally get the

> **Resulting inequality:**
>   \begin{align*}
> A_{m,n}&=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{n}{m-j}x^{m-j}\qquad  1\leq m \leq n,\quad x> 0\\
> \\
> 0<&(1+x)^2A_{m,n}^2(x)\\
> &+\binom{n-1}{m}\left(2x^2+\left(2-\frac{nm}{n-m}\right)x+n\right)A_{m,n}(x)\\
> &+\binom{n-1}{m}^2x\left(x-\frac{nm}{n-m}\right)\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Observe, that the only factors which could become negative in the equality above are 
>   \begin{align*}
> 2x^2+\left(2-\frac{nm}{n-m}\right)x+n\qquad\text{and}\qquad x-\frac{nm}{n-m}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   We see, that in case of fixed $x$ and growing $n$ the terms become more and more negative as $m$ is approaching $n$. But we also know that $A_{m,n}^2$ grows very fast, when $m$ approaches $n$. This is immediately clear if we consider
>   $$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}=2^n\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{j}=\frac{1}{2}2^{2m+1}$$

So, a *further elaboration* could have a look at the zeroes of (4) and try to analyse the resulting regions with negative values together with the growing behaviour of $A_{m,n}$.

> **Step 2:** Some special values

Which I did only for curiosity to get a first impression of the inequality. In the following we *always assume* $x>0$.

> *m=0* valid for $n\geq0$

You can see immediately that the inequality (1) is valid for all $x>0$ and $n\geq0$.

> *m=1* valid for $n>0$

This leads to the inequality $(n+x)^2-n>0$ which is also  valid for all $n>0$.

> *m=2* valid for $n>4$

With the help of Wolfram Alpha we find $n\geq 4.69858$ and $x>0$.

The corresponding inequality is

$$x^4+2nx^3+n(2n-1)x^2+n^2(n-1)x+\frac{1}{4}n^2(n-1)^2>0$$

> *m=n* valid for $n>0$.

with inequality

$$(x+1)^{n+1}-n>0$$

> *m=n-1* valid for $n>0$.

with inequality

$$\frac{1}{x}\left((x+1)^{n}-1\right)^2-\frac{n}{x}\left((x+1)^{n-1}\left(nx+(x+1)\right)+1\right)>0$$

> **Step 3:** Some additional info

Here is some related information which may be helpful when estimating the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m}$ for *large* values of $n$.

- A [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) from mathOverflow
- Another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84746/bounds-on-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk-and-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk1) from MSE
- and an interesting paper about [lower and upper bounds for sums of binomial coefficients](http://digbib.ubka.uni-karlsruhe.de/volltexte/181894) from Thomas Worsch.

Comment: @par: Thanks for accepting my answer and so granting the bounty. I'll keep this question in mind and will inform you, if something interesting comes up. Best regards.

Answer (score 4):

So we have

$$ \binom{n}{m} \sum_{j=0}^m j\binom{n}{m-j}x^j  <  x \left( \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{n}{m-j} x^j \right)^2 $$

or

$$ \binom{n}{m} \sum_{j=0}^m j\binom{n}{m-j}x^j  <  x \left( \sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{m-j} \binom{n}{m-k} x^j x^k\right) $$

or

$$ \binom{n}{m} \sum_{j=0}^m j\binom{n}{m-j}x^j  < x\left( \sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{m-j} \binom{n}{m-k} x^{j+k}\right) $$

On the right let $j=s+t$ and $k=t-s$ so $2t=j+k$ and $2s=j-k$.

$$ \binom{n}{m} \sum_{j=0}^m j\binom{n}{m-j}x^j  < x\left( \sum_{t=0}^m\sum_{s=-m}^m \binom{n}{m-s-t} \binom{n}{m-t+s} x^{t}\right) $$

Moving the $x$ into the summation and noting that for $j=0$ the summation on the right vanishes,

$$ \binom{n}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m j\binom{n}{m-j}x^j  < \left( \sum_{t=0}^m\sum_{s=-t}^t \binom{n}{m-s-t} \binom{n}{m-t+s} x^{t+1}\right) $$

Making the substitution $j=j-1$,

$$ \binom{n}{m} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(j+1)\binom{n}{m-j}x^{j+1}  < \sum_{t=0}^m  x^{t+1}\left( \sum_{s=-t}^t \binom{n}{m-s-t} \binom{n}{m-t+s}\right) $$

Linear independence of $x^j$ tells us that we require the following for all $j=0,...,m-1$

$$ \binom{n}{m}(j+1)\binom{n}{m-j} < \left( \sum_{s=-j}^j \binom{n}{m-s-j} \binom{n}{m-j+s}\right) $$

Rewriting this,

$$ \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}(j+1) \frac{n!}{(m-j)!(n-m+j)!} < \sum_{s=-j}^j \frac{n!}{(m-s-j)!(n-m+s+j)!}\frac{n!}{(m+s-j)!(n-m-s+j)!}$$

And this is exact. You can try to put this in MATLAB or excel to play around with various m and n.

One more simplification can be performed
$$ \frac{(j+1)}{m!(n-m)!(m-j)!(n-m+j)!} < \sum_{s=-j}^j \frac{1}{(m-s-j)!(n-m+s+j)!(m+s-j)!(n-m-s+j)!}$$

Comment: I don't see how the first two lines are equivalent. I assume "or" is short for, "or, equivalently" (i.e. iff).

Comment: Two aspects: The first inequality is of the form $0<P(x)$ with deg$P(x)=2m+1$, your last inequality with $x$ shows something different. What do you mean with linearity? Do you mean $P(x)>0$ iff all coefficients are $> 0$ ?

Comment: Think about how you would multiply. two $m-$nomial terms (two summations).  A single summation squared is a term by term multiplication in a double summation.

Comment: Not linearity, linear independence.  By that I mean the linear independence of polynomials $x^j$ for different j.

Comment: @InfiniteDifferenceMethod: Would you agree, that your last inequality with $x$ is of form $0 < Q(x)$ with $Q(x)$ a polynomial in $x$ of degree $m+1$? But the degree of $P(x)$ of your first inequality, written as $0 < P(x)$ is $2m+1$. Isn't it a discrepancy?

Comment: It's trivially true for the degrees greater than $m$ since $0<x$ implies that it holds for those terms.  So we drop them.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Mathematica gives a closed form in terms of the hypergeometric functions, which may or may not be helpful if you are proficient with them:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^m j \binom{n}{m-j} x^j = x \binom{n}{m-1}
{}_2F_1(2, 1-m; -m+n+2; -x)
$$

$$ \sum_{j=0}^m x^j \binom{n}{m-j} = \binom{n}{m} {}_2F_1
(1, -m; -m+n+1; -x) $$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+j+binomial%28n%2C+m-j%29+x%5Ej+for+j%3D0..m

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+binomial%28n%2C+m-j%29+x%5Ej+for+j%3D0..m

Comment: I don't see the connection with the question. Any hints how the hypergeometric functions could be applied to get sufficient conditions for the parameter? Best regards

Comment: None; the hypergeometric functions are not things I know much about. But since there are people who do know a lot about such things, I thought it reasonable to put this result up to give them a starting point.

Comment: Ok. I see your point and you're right.