# Adding Combinations - Math Contest

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

I am studying for a math test, and I'm wondering on an easier way to add combination series. For example, $12 \choose 3$ + $12 \choose 4$ + ... + $12 \choose 8$.
Is there an easier way than: $2^{12}$ - $12 \choose 2$... and etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only simplification I can think of is maybe exploiting the fact that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$, but that doesn't really make it that much faster.

Comment: It makes it perhaps a little faster: $$2^{12}-2(1+12+66)-\binom{12}3=4096-158-220=3938-220=3718\;,$$ all done as I was typing it out. But basically I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a closed form for this kind of sum is an inherently hard problem. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n and [Bounds on $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}x^k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}, m<n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84746/bounds-on-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk-and-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk1).

However, if you have a computer ( and some math software :-) ), you can take advantage of fast methods to evaluate the ordinary [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) at particular points since

[image]