# Closed form asymptotically

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

The bound for $$\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}2^i$$ is $O\left(3^n\right)$ but what will be the bound for $$\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\binom{n}{i}2^i$$ Any idea how should I proceed?

Comment: It should be clear that $3^n$ is still an upper bound, so to say the second sum is $O(3^n)$ is correct, the real question is for a bound that is both an upper and lower bound.

Comment: What you are asking is "what is the asymptotic bound of a partial binomial expansion", if that helps your research.

Comment: @DanielV yes I need bound for partial binomial expansion. Specially, I need the binomial expansion bound  from 1 to central.  Thank you. One bound i found as $2.82^ n$ by multiplying  all elements with $2^{n/2}$, but i seems it is not a tight bound.

Comment: This link may help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84746/bounds-on-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk-and-sum-k-0m-binomnkxk1. Use the symmetry of the summation coefficients to find the sum of _negative_ powers, and try applying the last formula on the page.

Comment: I do not see how you can get a bound of $2.82^n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\pp{\mathbb{P}}$$\Large\frac{1}{3^{2m}} \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{2m}{k}\ 2^k = \sum_{k=1}^m \binom{2m}{k}\ (\frac23)^k (\frac13)^{2m-k}$

$\large\ = \pp\Big(Bin(2m,\frac23) \in [1,m] \Big) < \exp(-\frac{m}{9})$   [by [the tail bound via Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_Bounds)]

Numerically, this is far from asymptotically tight, but at least it shows that $\large\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}\binom{n}{i}2^i \in o(3^n)$.